# Comparing dates in Lotus Notes search formulas

Tags: lotusscript, lotus-formula

In the code below I'm trying to find all the documents in which the date in the field duration is before the today's date

```
Set no = db.Search("Form=""formname"" & state=""3"" & duration<Today()", time, 0)
```

The field duration is of Date/Time type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first argument of NotesDatabase.Search must be a Notes formula language string. Functions in formula language start with the @ symbol, like this:

```
Set no = db.Search("Form=""formname"" & state=""3"" & duration<@Today", time, 0)
```